# Calculating the optimal size for the oracle undo tablepsace

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, tablespaces

To size the undo tablespace I query v$UNDOSTAT

```
SELECT BEGIN_TIME, END_TIME, UNDOBLKS, MAXQUERYLEN from v$UNDOSTAT;

BEGIN_TIME          END_TIME              UNDOBLKS MAXQUERYLEN
------------------- ------------------- ---------- -----------
14.10.2016 10:38:57 14.10.2016 10:48:13        911         244
14.10.2016 10:28:57 14.10.2016 10:38:57        977        1120
14.10.2016 10:18:57 14.10.2016 10:28:57       1031        2266
14.10.2016 10:08:57 14.10.2016 10:18:57       1018        2365 <--
```

To find out the blocksize of the undo tablespace, I query

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(value) DB_BLOCK_SIZE FROM v$parameter WHERE name = 'db_block_size';

DB_BLOCK_SIZE
-------------
         8192
```

Now I can calculate the undo tablespace size. I have to divide the UNDOBLKS by 600 to get the rate of undo generation in blocks per second, and multiply by the blocksize to get the figure in bytes. Multiply by the largest figure for MAXQUERYLEN to find the space needed if the highest rate of undo generates coincided with the longest query and then divide by a billion to get the answer in gigabytes

```
1018/600 * 8192*2365=328713557,33
328713557,33/1000000000=0.3287GB
```

Is this a correct calculation? Should I consider other metrics to calcualte the size of the undo tablepsace?

Comment: I think you just multiple the largest `undoblks` value by the `block size`. It's no more complicated than that.

Answer (score -1):

You may use the calculation mentioned in this site:

https://taliphakanozturken.wordpress.com/tag/actual-undo-size/

Comment: Please don't create link-only answers as they break if and when the link moves. You can include the link, but make the answer so it's self-sufficient without it. And: welcome here!